# Impact of using thinpool on LVM performance

Tags: performance, lvm, thin-provisioning

Using LVM, what are the performance implications of using `thinpool` on an logical volume?

Answer (score 4):

It depends of type of drive below it. When that's a ssd drive (where random access is simmilar to linear access) - there will be no difference. When using snapshot - there can be some performance boost.
But - if there is a magnetic drive(where random access is much slower than linear access) - there will be some performance loss because of jumps to different areas of disk.

Comment: What about the lookup of what blocks are where on the disk?

Comment: that's in metadata - and for "my" cases - metadata are small, so they're fully cached.

Answer (score 1):

In normal operation, none.  When snapshots are brought into the mix, thin provisioned LVs perform a lot better.

Comment: `In normal operation, none` -- How can this be true? There is an additional lookup of the block map in the meta volume for starters. How (metrics, measures) does thin-provisioning make performance `a lot better` with snapshots?

Comment: If you have a more specific question to ask, you should ask that as a new question, rather than try to expand the scope of your question in a comment on an answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to increase the scope of my question. I'm simply asking for some evidence for your assertions.